# Is this a legitimate way to reframe structuralism in the philosophy of mathematics?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, structuralism, numbers, truth-conditional-semantics

As an umbrella term, "structuralism" has to cover realist and nonrealist versions, while also carrying through the theme of its name nontrivially (for there is a trivial way to make structuralism true: just make the meaning of the word "structure" sufficiently ambiguous *and* vague and voila! everything can be made into an example of a pattern, even an empty or trivial pattern (with no or only one object of the pattern)). Can this be done by:

1. Using a truth-functional semantics for the domain of discourse? Where the meaningfulness of component terms is read primarily down from the encompassing truth-conditions rather than up from individual-object referents of the terms.
2. Propositionalism? Where the primary objects of mathematics are propositions, either "objectively" as abstract truth-theoretic objects or fictionalistically, as assertoric functions in fictional discourse.

Then the meaning of "2," for example, comes from the truth-conditions for propositions involving that very number, e.g. 2 + 2 = 4 is part of its "essential character," etc. (indeed, since 2 by 2 is 4 no matter which main-sequence arithmetic operator we use, this is arguably quite essentially characteristic of 2).

Comment: I don't think so. Domains of discourse are antithetical to the idea of structuralism as reducing objects to derivative placeholders, although I am not sure what "read down from the encompassing truth-conditions" means. Truth conditions in what terms? Propositionalism is also a mismatch because structuralists do want *something* (even if fictionalized) standing behind linguistic/descriptive content to which it can be said to refer.

Comment: Better ways to reframe structuralism could be predicate functor logic (PFL) or combinatorial logic (CL) on a surface syntactic (potentially shallow) level though...

Answer (score 1):

What you propose sounds really similar to Hellman's work from the 80s, who defends a mathematical structuralism *without structures* using modal logic. Specifically, from [*Structuralism in the Philosophy of Mathematics*](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/structuralism-mathematics/#Cons1980ResnShapHellEtc):

> Hellman’s **“modal structuralism”** is meant to be a systematic development of Putnam’s modalized if-then-ism. [..] For Hellman, a sentence such as “2+3=5” is analyzed as follows: Necessarily, for all relational systems M, if M is a model of the Dedekind-Peano axioms, then 2M+3M=5M. To avoid the non-vacuity problem, he adds the following assumption: Possibly, there exists an M such that M is a model of the Dedekind-Peano axioms. [..] As Hellman makes clear, **his goal is to develop a form of “structuralism without structures”** (Hellman 1996), since **the existence of abstract structures [..] is replaced by the modal aspects of his position** [..] Yet it is also not meant to rely on possibilia, i.e., possible objects existing in some shadowy sense. [..] **the modalities at issue** [..] are meant to be basic, i.e., the relevant possibilities and necessities are not reducible to anything further. On the other hand, they **are specified precisely in terms of laws of modal logic** (those of the system S5).

The main references are:

- Hellman, Geoffrey, 1996, “Structuralism Without Structures”, Philosophia Mathematica, 4(2): 100–123. doi:10.1093/philmat/4.2.100
- Hellman, Geoffrey and Stewart Shapiro, 2019, Mathematical Structuralism (Elements in The Philosophy of Mathematics), Cambridge: Cambridge University Press. doi:10.1017/9781108582933